# ASP.Net Core Web API returns HTTP 504 (Gateway Timeout) after adding Authorization via Cognito User Pool in AWS

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, amazon-cognito

I have develop a ASP.NET core web API and published to AWS Lambda. I have added the Authorize via the Cognito User Pool. But after adding the authorization it always returns a 504 Gateway Timeout HTTP code with the message  "Endpoint request timed out" when I am calling the API using postman. **But it is working very nicely for the localhost.**

Using the AWS API Gateway I have added an authorizer to the API. All the parameters like User pool Id, App Client Id , region and Client Secret are OK.

I added the [Authorize] attribute to the controllers and follow I added my code in the Startup.cs file.

Please help to solve this issue.

```
 public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        var region = Configuration["AWSCognito:Region"];
        var userPoolId = Configuration["AWSCognito:PoolId"];
        var appClientId = Configuration["AWSCognito:AppClientId"];
        var clientSecret = Configuration["AWSCognito:ClientSecret"];


        services.AddAuthentication("Bearer")
        .AddJwtBearer(options =>
        {
            options.Audience = appClientId;
            options.Authority = "https://cognito-idp." + region + ".amazonaws.com/" + userPoolId;
        });


        services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1);

        // Add S3 to the ASP.NET Core dependency injection framework.
        services.AddAWSService<Amazon.S3.IAmazonS3>();
        services.AddSingleton<IShoppingListService, ShoppingListService>();
        services.AddSingleton<ICompanyService, CompanyService>();
        services.AddSingleton<ICompanyRepository, CompanyRepository>();
    }



    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }
        else
        {
           app.UseHsts();
        }
        app.UseAuthentication();
        app.UseHttpsRedirection();
        app.UseMvc();
    }
```